# O que é a string de conexão "connectionString"?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, terminologia, connectionstring

O que é afinal de contas a *string* de conexão?

Numa *string* de conexão o que representa o `data-source`?

E o `provider name`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É um texto que passa as informações necessárias para o banco de dados estabelecer uma conexão com a aplicação. Obviamente precisa do endereço (normalmente inclui a porta) onde está o banco, que tipo é, a forma de conexão, o usuário, senha, etc.

Só lembrando que o ideal é evitar colocar o usuário e senha (especialmente esta), é melhor deixar usar outro tipo de autenticação mais segura. Mas se usar, que pelo menos seja criptografado.

Tem um [site dedicado a isto](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/).

O `Data Source` é o local onde estão os dados. Tem várias formas de indicar o local, pode ser um IP, por exemplo. É a mesma coisa que `Server`, `Address`, entre outros.

`ProviderName` não faz parte da *string* de conexão. Isto pode estar no [arquivo de configuração](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web.config). Se coloca nele qual é a DLL que será usada como cliente de acesso ao banco de dados. É nela que tem os códigos que vão estabelecer a conexão e toda comunicação de acesso aos dados. Isto ajuda definir que banco de dados será usado e quais textos de conexão serão válidos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado Brow... poderia me dizer como faço a conexão do VS2015 com Sqlserver 2016... estou a tentar a 3 dias e não consigo nada de jeito

Comment: Isto caberia em outra pergunta, mas ninguém vai conseguir fazer pra você se você não souber o que colocar. Se o site que eu passei não te ajudar, eu tenho dúvidas se será fácil te ajudar.

Comment: é que eu não estou percebendo muito bem...

Comment: Mas obrigado na mesma

Answer (score 1):

Cara tu pode criar a string de conexão usando um arquivo de extensão .udl. Basta criar um arquivo texto, alterar a extensão para "udl", abrir o arquivo configurar com os dados para conectar com teu banco ( Host, username, pass), salva este arquivo, altera para .txt, abre e copia o texto ali dentro. Está pronta sua string de conexão :)
Abraço.